# 'For' loop on command line in Z shell ('zsh'): "parse error near `done'"

Tags: for-loop, command-line, zsh, parse-error

Why am I getting this error? It seems like good syntax to me.

```
for f in todo/family/* ; echo "$f" ; done
```

Output:

> zsh: parse error near `done'

This is on the regular command line - not in a file.

Comment: You need a `do`. `for f in todo/family/*; do echo "$f"; done`

Comment: BTW, while it doesn't *generally* support zsh, this is one that http://shellcheck.net/ would catch (insofar as the syntax you're trying to use is taken from the POSIX sh family, and thus also compatible with sh/ksh/bash/dash).

Comment: There is a shortened one-line form of the `for` loop in `zsh`, though: `for f (todo/family/*); echo "$f"`. No `do`, `in`, or `done` keywords needed, and the list goes in parentheses after the index variable. Only a single sublist is allowed in the body in that case.

Comment: (It's probably best to read `man zshmisc`, especially under "Alternate forms for complex commands", to understand exactly what can and cannot be represented using the short form.)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - for sure you found it. Thanks for the spell check idea I’ll take a look at implementing that into my environment.  Please submit an answer and I’ll accept :)

Comment: I commented, vs answering, because I'm not sure the question is within site guidelines -- see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137395/are-questions-solved-by-fixing-a-typo-or-basic-syntax-error-too-localized; the basic question re: too-localized is whether someone else with the same problem will be able to find and benefit from the question and its answers -- it's tricky to cut through the noise on "parse error near done" and come up with terms someone else with the same mistake will find, since there are so many different errors that manifest in the same way.

Comment: ...anyhow, feel free to self-answer with content I  first provided in a comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - at the risk of having this question flagged for deletion later - I'm going to leave it with a well formatted answer.  I hope that going the extra mile and showing how to find these problems using the spellcheck command as you suggested will have some value to future visitors.  Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Missing `do` in my command.

As per [CharlesDuffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907320/for-loop-on-command-line-in-z-shell-zsh-parse-error-near-done/52954252#comment92725472_52907320), this is clearly a typo/missing syntax related problem.

```
What I wrote:  for f in todo/family/* ; echo "$f" ; done
#                                      ^ missing do

Bash expected: for f in todo/family/* ; do echo "$f" ; done
```

Clearly this error/typo is visible using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (another great resource).

---

### How to check Bash-related syntax errors:

#### 1. Go to ShellCheck and paste this in:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in todo/family/* ; echo "$f" ; done
```

You will see the error clearly:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 3:
for f in todo/family/* ; echo "$f" ; done
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this for loop. Fix to allow more checks.
                         ^-- SC1058: Expected 'do'.
                         ^-- SC1072: Expected 'do'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Add `do` with a space, just before `echo` and everything checks out:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in todo/family/* ; do echo "$f" ; done
```

into ShellCheck - you can see there is no error.  Remove the `do` and you will see what my problem was.

#### 2. Optionally, you could [install the `shellcheck` command](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#installing)